# Отдельная функция или сплошной код?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли смысл выносить код в отдельную функцию если он встречается на странице только один раз? Влияет ли это на производительность или только на удобство чтения кода? Может есть какие-то подводные камни?

Никак не могу найти статьи в интернете на эту тему, везде встречается фраза - плохой стиль.

Есть кнопка, при нажатии которой выполняются определенные действия:

```
<button class="details" onclick="
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('details'); 
for (;x[0];) { 
x[0].className = 'det';}">Все характеристики</button>
```

Есть вариант вынести весь код в отдельную функцию и написать так:

```
<button class="details" onclick="my_func()">Все характеристики</button>
```

И всё-таки как лучше сделать? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: функция оф корз. в кнопке я б лично даже `onclick="my_func()"` не оставлял бы. всё в коде биндил бы.........`или только на удобство чтения кода` - не только читаемость, но и разделять надо. а еще и тестировать код некоторые любят)

Comment: если код 100% не будет никогда меняться - без разницы

Comment: @Grundy ты сам в такое веришь-то? %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, зачёт сдал и забыл?))

Comment: Плохой стиль - это очень серьезный аргумент, если Вы занимаетесь программированием профессионально или постоянно-любительски, и вообще не имеет значения, если вам лабу сдать и на всю оставшуюся жизнь забить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, конечно :-) только. как я понимаю всю это портянку можно заменить простым: `this.className='det'`. Хотя нет :-) живая коллекция такая живая :)

Comment: Одна функция будет скомпилирована быстрее и лучше, но, конечно, это не тот случай, где имеет смысл гнаться за производительностью. Тут, полагаю, обновление выборки на каждой итерации будет вредить куда сильнее. И при этом, если элементов не несколько тысяч, это всё равно будет слишком быстро, чтобы переживать о скорости.

(Хотя, конечно, так писать нельзя.)

Comment: В более-менее серьезных программах, есть такой аргумент как "удобство отладки", то есть не просто чтения человеком, а еще и изучения инструментами разработки. Первый вариант (портянка в инлайн обработчике) хрен отладишь.

Comment: @SurfinBird эта информация парню только навредит. Кстати я думаю если у кого-то идет погоня за копейками производительности которые дают инлайн обработчики, так я думаю у них хватит ресурсов запилить свою штуку, которая на сервер сайд рендере js инлайнить будет. Ручками такое писать точно не надо.

Comment: @SurfinBird, _Одна функция будет скомпилирована быстрее и лучше_ - так тут и так одна функция

Comment: @Grundy я понял это как "инлайн обработчик сработает на микрокопейки быстрее", что вероятно на некоторых движках действительно так =) Невнимательно прочитал короче

Comment: А, прошу прощения, пропустил «один раз». Тогда без разницы, по идее.

Comment: @Утка, скорее не сработает, а _навесится_ быстрее, в остальном все то же самое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короткий ответ: вынести в отдельную функцию.

Длинный ответ.

Лично я предпочитаю следовать такому порядку разработки:

1. Сделайте, чтобы работало (но никому это не показывайте). На этом шаге можно написать что-то похожее на то, что у вас сейчас.
2. Сделайте, чтобы ваш код было удобно читать и понимать. Здесь вы выносите код в отдельную функцию, понятным образом ее называете, форматируете отступами, навешиваете обработчик через javascript, а не в атрибуте html и т. д. Получается вариант, который уже можно куда-то выкладывать или сдавать работу.
3. Если осталось желание или есть необходимость, начинайте оптимизировать производительность. Скорее всего, этот пункт плавно перейдет в новую итерацию пункта 1.

Вы сейчас находитесь на шаге 1. Двигайтесь дальше!